# Do you need permission to use your own work when working for an agency?

Tags: freelance, portfolio

For the past year I have been working for an agency as an intern. It is now the end and I want to build a portfolio of the work I have done.

Do I need the agency's permission to use the work I created for their clients? It is my own work that I created but belongs to the agency as they paid me a wage for the work done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, for portfolio display, No. You do not need permission.
 
You can display your work in your portfolio.

**However**, this assume there is no **secret, proprietary, confidential** information in the pieces. If the pieces contain **any** such information, you should seek permission first. Displaying confidential information, even if in a portfolio, can result in problems. It's not about copyrights, it's about confidentiality.

Comment: There is no confidential parts in any of the work it is mainly graphic design and If there is info like a name or address on something like a business card I will be using Lorem Ipsum dummy text instead of the real information I am also showcasing sites I have created for their clients and those website are live, I assume the work still partly belongs to me as I created it or does it souly belong to the agency I created it for/the client is was sold to ?

Comment: Well, if you were an **employee** the work belongs **entirely** to your *employer*. However, portfolio display is customarily seen as "fair use" and permissible. But you shouldn't think you "own" anything.

Comment: Thanks, So under the fair use act I can display it on my portfolio would this be the case If I wanted to set up my own business could i still use that work in a portfolio section on the site? or does the fair use only fall under a 'personal porfolio'

Comment: You created the work, so you can generally display it. You just can't *sell* it.  Worse case is an employer would tell you to stop. You're worrying needlessly for a portfolio. You'll be fine.

Comment: The work doesn't have to belong to you in order for you to tell people that you made it. The websites are public (I suppose) so why shouldn't you be able to show them? I wouldn't recommend changing the text on business cards to dummy text - it doesn't look too good and it makes it look like it is not a real project. If it is not a secret company then why would their business cards be secret?

Comment: @MadsWolff -- I wasn't referring to things like business cards. Obviously you'd remove any direct contact information anywhere. I have created Annual Reports or Sales materials that contained confidential financial statements for a company... I can **never** display these pieces due to this. It's that type of situation I was referring to.

Comment: @Metis My employer and I are in a dispute over unpaid wages of £4k so I'd thought I'd ask as things are a little heated and bad at the moment so long as I can use my own work without my past employers permission it will be all good as he is the kind of person who will try and get it taken down because of the unpaid wage. **Mads Wolff** Thanks I will take that into consideration non of the projects I worked on were secret or had confidential information on them.

Comment: You created it.. if he didn't pay for it.. then you *may* own it. If you worked without pay, the odds are in your favor, not his. (But I'm not a lawyer).

Comment: @Metis. My comment was for the OP who talks about changing the text on business cards to Lorem Ipsum. That is just a shame in my opinion. It is just employees in a company who can be easily googled. But of course, confidential stuff is no go.

Comment: I don't use Lorem Ipsum, I use fake names (or cartoon character names) and (clearly) fake numbers but mix them up. You get all the visual aspects without the distraction of clearly dummy text. I've designed several business card for Eric Cartman :)

Comment: The unpaid wage is over a 7 month period when I was paid an apprenticeship wage but I wasn't on an apprenticeship I should of been paid £7.50 an hour but only got £3.40, I didn't bring it up though because I was promised a full time job and good wage but that didn't happen (i was basically lied to) so turned a blind eye for 7 months so long as I can use my own work in a portfolio and he can't do anything legally about it, It's all good Thank you guys !

Comment: @Metis. That is an ok solution. But taking account for the length of the names in the company is also part of the design (it's a bit geeky - I know).

Comment: @user3112634 ah that old trick. If you arent now paid a salary that says they respect you then they dont respect you and that is not going to change.